# How to add new files to already created git patch?

Tags: git

I wanted to add new files to already created patch. I searched for commands using 'man' but didn't work.
Does somebody know how to do this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean one created with `git-format-patch`?

Comment: No. I used git diff --cached > index.patch

Answer (score 0):

If you by "patch" mean commit, you can use `git commit --ammend` to add new changes to the previous commit. Remember to stage the new changes using `git add .` or `git add <your files>` before you commit again.

Comment: I have created the patch using, git diff <file_names> > /some_location/abc.patch. Now I have an abc.patch file. Later on I have changed some files which are in abc.patch. Now I want to add these new changes to abc.patch

Answer (score 0):

> *I used git diff --cached > index.patch*

In which case rather than changing the patch file, make the changes to your Git working copy, add them to the staging area (ie. `git add`), and make a new patch with `git diff --cached > index.patch`.

If you've already committed and moved on, checkout that commit again, apply the patch (but don't add or commit it), make whatever changes you like, and then `git diff > index.patch`.

Basically, don't try to edit the patch file, generate a new one.